# how to bind the selected item from the combobox to textblock inside datagrid

Tags: wpf

I am having `combobox` inside datagrid which is inside cell editing template.

What i want is that when a user select an item from the `combobox` and move to the next cell, the selected item must bind to the `textblock` of that same cell.

if anyone knows how to do help me. here is my xaml

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
          Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Name="attendancegrid" Background="#FFDCE8EB" CanUserAddRows="False" 
          BorderBrush="Chocolate" BorderThickness="5" RowHeight="30" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FFB74646" IsReadOnly="False" Foreground="Black" Loaded="attendancegrid_Loaded"
          SelectionChanged="attendancegrid_SelectionChanged" CurrentCellChanged="attendancegrid_CurrentCellChanged"
          CellEditEnding="attendancegrid_CellEditEnding">

    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Monday" Width="100">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ComboBox x:Name="monday" Width="50"   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true"   Loaded="monday_Loaded" SelectionChanged="monday_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="staff" Width="50" Loaded="staff_Loaded"></ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel >
                    <TextBlock x:Name="mon"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: what type of items you have in combobox? strings?

Comment: post all relevant code: events and loading data.

Comment: i am having string i can bind the combobox using loaded event

Answer (score 1):

You have to create one collection property to be bound on Combobox like

```
public List<string> MyCollection{get;set;}
```

and one string property for binding it to the SelectedItem of ComboBox and Your TextBlock like

```
private string _SelectedCollectionItem;

public string SelectedCollectionItem
{
    get{return _SelectedCollectionItem;}
    set{_SelectedCollectionItem=value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCollectionItem");}
}
```

now in your xaml do like this

```
DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" SelectedItem={Binding SelectedCollectionItem,Mode=TwoWay}></ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel >
                <TextBlock Text={Binding SelectedCollectionItem}></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: Download GalaSoft MVVMLight Toolkit and add reference to your project.